# Creating a string of specific length using Markov chain

Tags: r, markov-chains

I'm trying to simulate a homogeneous finite state Markov chain in R. I want to get an output of some specific length given initial probability and transition probability matrix. This is what I have so far

```
 library(markovchain)
 words <- c("h", "e", "l", "o")

 ###Initial probability
 initial <- cbind(c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25))

# define the transition matrix (each row sums to 1)
transitions <-  rbind(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4),
                  c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4),
                  c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4),
                  c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4))

rownames(transitions) <- colnames(transitions) <- words

library(markovchain)
markovChain <- new("markovchain", states=words, 
               transitionMatrix = transitions)

markovchainSequence(10, markovChain, t0="h")
```

This code, however, is not using initial probability. I only state that the state at t0 the state should be b. How can I use initial probability over here?

Comment: Replace `t0="h"` with `t0 = your_sampler`. You see? Your "initial probability" is weird, why it has only two numbers? You don't want to sample one of the four letters?

Comment: That's right. I made a mistake there. So what you are saying is that I should replace 'h' with t0=initial?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've made the correction.

Comment: What I meant is given in @G5W's answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an initial state using your initial probabilities.

```
M0 = sample(words, 1,  prob=initial)
markovchainSequence(10, markovChain, t0=M0)
```